# What is meant by this function sending $\def\p{\mathbf p}\p$ to a column with components $\p(-1),\p(0),\p(1)$?

Tags: linear-algebra

I received [this function](https://i.stack.imgur.com/n7Vj5.jpg) on my homework, and I'm not quite sure what it means.

> Define $T:\mathbb P_2 \to \mathbb R^3$ by
>
> $$
> T\left(\mathbf{p}\right) =
> \begin{bmatrix} 
> \mathbf{p}\left(-1\right)\\
> \mathbf{p}\left(0\right)\\
> \mathbf{p}\left(1\right)
> \end{bmatrix}
> $$
>
> - Show $T$ is linear.
> - Show $T$ is injective.
> - Is $T$ invertible? What does this mean?

From what I garner, $T$ is a linear transformation that maps from irrational numbers (not sure what the sub $2$ means?) to $\mathbb R^3$, real numbers to third dimension.

I'm not looking for answers to the questions, I don't understand what the function/transformation is doing.

The $\mathbf p$ is presumably a vector? What is meant by the $-1, 0,$ and $1$ in the parentheses then? It can't be simply multiplying because that would map to $\mathbb P^3$, not $\mathbb R^3$, right?

Comment: You have no references for this class in which the notation is defined? Mapping from irrational numbers would make no sense in this context.  Based on context, $P_2$ is probably the vector space of polynomials of degree at most $2$.

Comment: I am not sure what you are asking, but this is all the information that was given to me for this question. So what would a vector p in P_2 look like?

Comment: There is no textbook?  Class notes?  An instructor?  It is just assumed you know what all notation is without definition?  I was wondering how this would be in a homework assignment without access to a definition of what it is referring to.

Comment: The vectors are polynomials, which can be thought of as functions.

Answer (score 1):

As you are not looking for answers, here is my interpretation of the question (I am sue this is what it means). The domain, as pointed out in Jonas Meyer's comment is the vector space consisting of all polynomials $p(x)$ of the form $p(x)=ax^2+bx+c$. You have guessed the codomain correctly.

What the function $T$ does is: it takes a polynomial as input, and outputs a 3d-vector consisting of the values of that polynomial at  three elements of its domain, namely,  $-1, 0$, and $+1$ in that order.

Comment: So, something like $x^2 + 2x$ would be in the domain? And it would map to the vector (3, 0, -1)

Comment: Yes. That is something I have already said. Elements of $P_2$ are polynomials of the form $ax^2+bx+c$, with $a,b,c$ real numbers. Your example corresponds to $a=1,b=2,c=0$. If you take $a=0$ this will include all lower degree polynomials, linear as well as constants.